# Is there a way to add a loader component to the Material ui Autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll to my autocomplete component and it looks something like this

```
const SearchSelect: React.FC<SearchSelectProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <Autocomplete
            {...props}
            ListboxProps={{
                onScroll: (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
                    const listboxNode = event.currentTarget
                    if (
                        listboxNode.scrollTop + listboxNode.clientHeight ===
                        listboxNode.scrollHeight
                    ) {
                        props.loadmoreresults && props.loadmoreresults()
                    }
                },
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label={props.label}
                    variant="filled"
                />
            )}
        />
    )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SearchSelect)
```

I would like to add a loader component at the end of the list every time I scroll to the bottom of it. If that is not possible, at least adding a text "Loading" at the end. How would you do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I finally found how to do it using the `renderOption` prop, as follows:

```
           renderOption={(option: any) => {
                if (option === props.options[props.options.length - 1] && props.hasNextPage) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            {option.label}
                            <Loader />
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                return option.label
            }}
```

EDIT: this will add a loader to the last item, it will not be separated from the last option so it might not be suitable for you if you're looking to add an extra component under the list. To do that, you can create your custom Paper component and add it through the `PaperComponent` prop:

```
function CustomPaper({ children, ...others }) {
    return (
        <Paper variant="outlined" {...others}>
            {children}
            <Loader />
        </Paper>
    )
}
```